# Unable to run vlc on windows7

Tags: java, vlcj

I am getting a problem while running an embedded vlc player in my javafx application on windows7. It is working fine on windows10 and other distro but strange getting following console error when start the application.

```
Native library (win32-x86-64/libvlc.dll) not found in resource path (
client-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:302)
        at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:455)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1722)
        at com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1443)
        at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc.<clinit>(LibVlc.java:98)
        at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.support.version.LibVlcVersion.<init>(LibVlcVersion
.java:49)
```

Comment: Is VLC installed on windows 10?

Comment: yes offcourse.. Even that i try to add the path as suggested in some other post like this:    NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("libvlc", "c:/program files (x86)/videolan/vlc");

Comment: Is it there on windows 7 as well?

Comment: yes it is installed on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to load libvlc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885679/unable-to-load-libvlc)

Comment: It is possible that you installed 32Bit VLC on Win7 etc.